# sqlite database android error

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I Have a problem in `getWritableDatabase()`

```
private SQLiteDatabase bdd;

    public posteBD(Context context){

        Mabasededonnees Mabasededonnees = new Mabasededonnees(context, NOM_BDD, null, VERSION_BDD);
    }
    public void open(){
        //on ouvre la BDD en écriture
        bdd = Mabasededonnees.getWritableDatabase();
    }
```

The error in eclipse

> Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getWritableDatabase() from the type SQLiteOpenHelper

i have a file Mabasededonnees.java (`SQLiteOpenHelper`)

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you are French;)

Already trying to respect the naming convention, it avoids many errors ... variable names always start with not a tiny

MyDatabase MyDatabase = new MyDatabase (context, dbname, null, VERSION_BDD);

Eclipse you do not propose to resolve the concern itself?

> Apparemment tu es français ;)
>
> Déjà essaye de respecter les
>   convention de nommage, ça évite pas
>   mal d'erreur... les noms de variables
>   commencent toujours pas une minuscule
>
> MaBaseDeDonnees maBaseDeDonnees = new
>   MaBaseDeDonnees(context, NOM_BDD,
>   null, VERSION_BDD);
>
> Eclipse ne te propose pas de régler le
>   soucis lui même ?

Comment: Merci beaucoup, en fait l'erreur est a cuse du majuscule et minuscule

Comment: Tu vois ;) Tu peux marquer mon post au vert, ce qui indiquera qu'il t'a aider ?